# Compare the value to another workbook with 2 rules that need to be pass both

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have been trying to check the condition using VBA, but now I am struggling
here is the explanation of what I am doing

1. if there's any 'uncheck' on condition(A) column
2. then, The objective is comparison between **data2 and data4 (which is the data of that itself uncheck condition)** with **data2 and data4 in another workbook (photo2)** (not another worksheet)
3. To compare it to *another workbook (photo2)*, I need to compare whether the value in *data2(C) column in (photo1)* exists in *data 2 in another workbook (photo2)* if not we conclude that *not pass as a final result in F column*

   > for example, as you can see A5 & A7 in photo2 pass 1st rule because they have the same value as C5 & C7
4. here is the difficult part, when it pass 3.) rule, then I need to compare *data4(E) column in (photo1)* to *data4 in another workbook (photo2)*
   But the rule is the value does not need to be exactly the same. however if *the data4 value in another workbook (photo2)* isn't more/less than 50 compare to *the value in data4 in photo1* then we conclude that *pass as a final result*

   > for example, as you can see from 3.) A5 & A7 pass rule but in 4.) only
   > A5 with 220 pass because the difference is 20 compare to 200 which in
   > range 150-250 (200+-50)

photo1

[image: photo 1]

photo2

[image: photo2]

Is there any formula/vlookup/vba or whatever to run it?

Comment: Please include the code you've written so far.  That way, we can help you edit your code so that it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the following data in your worksheets

Worksheet `Photo1`
[image]

Worksheet `Photo2`
[image]

you can use this formula in `result` in column F

```
=IF(A2="uncheck",IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(C2,Photo2!A:A,0))),IF(ABS(INDEX(Photo2!B:B,MATCH(C2,Photo2!A:A,0))-E2)<=50,"pass","not pass"),"not pass"),"not pass")
```

---

Explanation what the formula does

```
=IF(A2="uncheck",
    IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(C2,Photo2!A:A,0))),
        IF(ABS(INDEX(Photo2!B:B,MATCH(C2,Photo2!A:A,0))-E2)<=50,"pass","not pass"),
    "not pass"),
"not pass")
```

This part `IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(C2,Photo2!A:A,0)))` checks if `data2` exists in `Photo2` if not it does not match and returns an error (not pass) if there is no error `NOT(ISERROR` it will check the following:

```
IF(ABS(INDEX(Photo2!B:B,MATCH(C2,Photo2!A:A,0))-Photo1!E2)
```

Where `INDEX(Photo2!B:B,MATCH(C2,Photo2!A:A,0))` will pull the `data4` value from `Photo2` by matching the `data2` from `Photo1` with the `data2` from the `Photo2` with `MATCH(C2,Photo2!A:A,0)`. Then subtract `data4` from `Photo1` get the absolute value `ABS` of it and test if this is `<=50`. Then it is `pass` otherwise not.

Comment: (1/2) Thank you very much. I appreciate it. I just started learning excel and I think there are a lot of things that I need to learn.
However, when I paste this formula in result in column F. It shows ‘#SPILL!’ So I think it failed because the unclear where the file located in. then I try to replace photo1/photo2 that you given with 'E:\Introduction to Excel\[photo2.xlsx]Sheet1'
Fyi : both workbook file located in E:\Introduction to Excel with .xlsx file extension

Comment: (2/2) =IF(A:A="uncheck",IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(C:C,'E:\Introduction to Excel\[photo2.xlsx]Sheet1'!A:A,0))),IF(ABS(INDEX('E:\Introduction to Excel\[photo2.xlsx]Sheet1'!B:B,MATCH(C:C,'E:\Introduction to Excel\[photo2.xlsx]Sheet1'!A:A,0))- 'E:\Introduction to Excel\[photo1.xlsx]Sheet1'!E:E)<=50,"pass","not pass"),"not pass"),"not pass")
But the result is still ‘#SPILL!’
Could you give any suggestion please?

Comment: @Reetagon Try `=IF(A2="uncheck",IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(C2,Photo2!A:A,0))),IF(ABS(INDEX(Photo2!B:B,MATCH(C2,Photo2!A:A,0))-E2)<=50,"pass","not pass"),"not pass"),"not pass")` in cell `F2` instead and pull the formula down.

Comment: Thank you so much! It’s worked. Perhaps If I want to play around like have 3 different results. (1.) For check the result is always prepared. (2.) For uncheck (2.1) If they have both conditions  = pass (2.2) if they have not or only either = not pass                       
And I have more question (1) if I add letters to data2 such as abc123456789, def234567891, … (2.) Or set data4 as number format (in form of money)                     
So, what I need to adjust in formula in both case.

Comment: Please edit your original quesiton and add more details. I don't understand the first part of your comment. • If you add letters nothing needs to be changed. If you set the number format nothing needs to be changed (it only compares the numeric value no matter if the number format is the same. So if the value is `400` and one is number format `400.00 €` they are still the same.

Comment: At first, we set only 2 result which is pass/not pass. but if i want 3 result and changing all the wording such as (1) if condition is 'NEW' result always be 'NEW' as previous. (2) if condition is 'RENEW' and it have both data2 & data4(+-100) then the result is 'TRANSFER' but (3) if they don't have both or only have either data2 or data4(+-100) then the result is 'RENEW’ as previous. Am i confusing you?

Comment: And im trying apply with your formula which is =IF(A2=”NEW”,”NEW”,IF(A2="RENEW",IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(C2,Photo2!A:A,0))),IF(ABS(INDEX(Photo2!B:B,MATCH(C2,Photo2!A:A,0))-E2)<=100,"TRANSFER","RENEW"),"RENEW"),"RENEW")) but it show the error ‘#NAME?’ can you give me any advise?

Comment: @Helloworld yes very confusing. Please use the original question do describe things, comments are too short to explain things properly. Also example data would and expected outcome would be good to have for better understanding of your condition description. the `#Name?` error means that a name in your formula is not correct. Probably `Photo2` or `Photo1` is not the correct sheet name or the sheets do not exist in the same workbook (and therefore need full workbook reference). Please check.